# How to open a specific file using an env variable path with a command in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to mimic a command I had in Sublime Text: it'd open the specific file from the Command Palette with this snippet:

```
{
    "caption": "My Library",
    "command": "open_file_env",
    "args":
    {
        "platform": "Windows",
        "file": "$LIBSFOLDER/my_library.jsx"
    },
},
```

— so this would resolve the `$LIBSFOLDER` to a path and open the `my_library.jsx` file.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to do the same in VSC without much luck. `Ctrl+P` won't work because it's workspace-based, I want a global shortcut.

I tried to use `multiCommand` and `command-runner` extensions with this command:

```
{
            "command": "multiCommand.openLibrary",
            "label": "My Library",
            "sequence": [
                {
                    "command": "command-runner.run",
                    "args": {
                        "command": "start \"C:/path_to_vscode/Code.exe\" \"D:/path_to_libraries/layers.jsx\""
                    }
                },
            ]
}
```

and this works with three issues:

- this opens Terminal;
- path to VSCode is hardcoded (I'd like to use this on Mac and Windows)
- path to the library file is hardcoded (I'd like to use an enviro variable)

So, what would be the best way to open a specific file that's not in the workspace on any OS using an environmental variable as a folder?

Maybe I should consider a different approach: maybe it's possible to add files to something like 'global workspace' so that they'd be available in `Ctrl+P`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) v0.13.0

You can use the command [`htmlRelatedLinks.openFile`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file)

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+i m",   // or any other combo
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "${env:LIBSFOLDER}/my_library.jsx",
      "method": "vscode.open",
      "viewColumn": "split"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For some reason this works when I put a full path but doesn't work when I put an env variable, I'm getting an error: `Unable to resolve non-existing file '\${env:SCRIPTSFOLDER}\libraries\utilities.jsx').`. Do I need to do anything else so that VSC could resolve it..? Can I somehow test if it sees the variable or something..?

Comment: could it be because I actually can't use vars in settings? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809

Comment: the resolve of the `${env:}` is done by the extension, I have tested the command as part of a multi command and it works with a full path and with an environment variable. Does the environment variable exist in the shell that is used to launch VSC? If you use version 0.13.0 the `${env:}` should be replaced by `Unknown` if the environment var does not exist. Check version in extension bar.

Comment: it exists: if I type `$ENV:SCRIPTSFOLDER` in VSC console it shows a correct path, if I type a checker in there with the full path it says that file exists. The extension version is 0.13.0. Here's [a screenshot with the keybinding, terminal outputs and error message](https://i.imgur.com/f06yhkG.png). Anything else I could try..?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy It depends on which process/shell is used to launch VSC, that is the environment it uses.Exit VSC, Start a PowerShell, verify that the required env var exists, start vsc FROM THIS shell, execute the command, Check if line 239 of the extension contains `uri.replace(/\$\{env:([^}]+)\}/,`. In v0.13.1 I have added log statement to see which environment var is found, you have to enable setting `htmlRelatedLinksProvider.enableLogging`, look in the Help/Developer_Tools console of VSC for `Use environment variable: xxxxxxx`

Comment: Hmm I started VSC from powershell, I ticket a property in the Settings (it added `"html-related-links.enableLogging": true,`), but it didn't log anything in the console :/ the version is 0.13.1. I even added line `console.log('Hello')` in `extension.js` but it didn't print out in the console. Oh this is so confusing

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy It is the console of the Developer Tools, from the Help menu, VSC is a "Web Browser" using Google Chrome, which console are you looking at?, It should log `Clicked at: xxxxx` in all versions of the extension, where did you add `console.log('Hello');`, which line number

Comment: yes, that's where I'm looking, [here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/BaoP3ze.png)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy The fact that you don't see your `HELLOO` log and that `${env:xxx}` is not replaced means that this code is not executed, do you have multiple versions of the extension in the `.vcsode/extensions` folder? Are you working with VSC remote? I have tested it outside the dev setup and I see the logs in the DevTools Console. If you try with one of the other supported variables do they get replaced? If you add an illegal JS line in the code does it crash (no functionality of the command) `throw new Error();` be sure to reload the window. You get a log line in dev tools.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy After adding the `throw` - Reload Window - Test: I get the error of command failed. Removing the `throw` - Reload Window - Test: Command works again but no console logs. Exit VSC. Restart VSC from shell and now logs are back again